# Flutter single `DataCell` color

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm trying to do something similar to the Excel/Google Sheets/etc can do and add a background colour to just one single `DataCell` on my `DataTable`. I could only find a reference to set an entire `DataRow`, not just one cell. Does anyone know how?

API reference:

- DataCell: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataCell-class.html
- DataRow: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataRow-class.html

What I've tried so far:

```dart
DataCell(
  FittedBox(
    child: test
        ? ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(variable),
            ),
          )
        : Center(
            child: Text(variable),
          ),
  ),
),
```

What I got:

[image: Cell partially filled with the colour]

Goal:

[image: Cell fully filled with the colour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by removing the `FittedBox` from the widget tree.

```dart
DataCell(
  test
      ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(variable, style: style),
            ),
          ),
        )
      : Center(
          child: Text(variable, style: style),
        ),
),
```

End result:

[image: DataTable with DataCell completely painted in orange]

PS: The `Padding` here is just so that the colour stays within the `VerticalDivider` indents (at the sides).