# Fill width in single datacell in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm trying to accomplished something like had been issued here : [Flutter single `DataCell` color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325592/flutter-single-datacell-color)
I want to grey out the cell to let user know that was supposed to leave blank. Currently I manage to fill the height of datacell but the width.

my code snippet:

```
_data[i][newColumn] = Container(
 width: double.infinity,
 height: double.infinity,
 color: Colors.grey,
  child: Text(''));
```

Result: Last cell at the most right which fill up height space only:

[image]

full code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class InspectionSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const InspectionSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InspectionSheet> createState() => _InspectionSheetState();
}

class _InspectionSheetState extends State<InspectionSheet> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey();

  bool validate = false;
  TextEditingController ctrlsampleSize = TextEditingController();

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _data = [
    {
      //"checkitemID": "0",
      "Ballooning No": "1",
      "Datatype": "1",
      "Specifications": ".325+-0.020",
      "Tool": "CALIPER",
      "LSL": "0.305",
      "Target": "2",
      "USL": "0.325",
      "Tol-": "0.02",
      "Tol+": "0.02",
      "Image": "",
      "WI": ""
    },
    {
      //"checkitemID": "0",
      "Ballooning No": "2",
      "Datatype": "2",
      "Specifications": ".325+-0.020",
      "Tool": "CALIPER",
      "LSL": "0.305",
      "Target": "2",
      "USL": "0.325",
      "Tol-": "0.02",
      "Tol+": "0.02",
      "Image": "",
      "WI": ""
    },
   
  ];

  late List<String> _columnNames;
  //String _selectedValue = inputList.first;
  String _selectedValue = 'PASS';

  void startbutton() {
    validateEmpty();
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      addDataCol();
    }
  }

  void validateEmpty() {
    //if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    //  // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
    //  // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
    // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    //    const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
    // );
    ctrlsampleSize.text.isEmpty ? validate = false : validate = true;
    //}
  }

  void addDataCol() {
    int colNo = int.parse(ctrlsampleSize.text);
    if (colNo < 1) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= colNo; i++) {
        _addColumn('Data $i');
      }
    });
  }

  void _addColumn(String newColumn) {
    if (_columnNames.contains(newColumn)) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= _data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (_data[i]['Datatype'] == '1') {
          _data[i][newColumn] = TextFormField();
        } else if (_data[i]['Datatype'] == '2') {
          _data[i][newColumn] = DropdownButton<String>(
              value: _selectedValue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_outlined),
              elevation: 16,
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items:
                  // inputList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  //   return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  //     value: value,
                  //     child: Text(value),
                  //     onTap: () {
                  //       _selectedValue = value;
                  //     },
                  //   );
                  // }).toList(),
                  [
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'PASS',
                  child: const Text('PASS'),
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedValue = 'PASS';
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'FAIL',
                  child: const Text('FAIL'),
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedValue = 'FAIL';
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'UAI',
                  child: const Text('UAI'),
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedValue = 'UAI';
                  },
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'NA',
                  child: const Text('NA'),
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedValue = 'NA';
                  },
                )
              ]);
        } else if (_data[i]['Datatype'] == '3') {
          if (newColumn == 'Data 1') {
            _data[i][newColumn] = TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _displayTextInputDialog(context);
                },
                child: const Text('-'));
          } else {
            _data[i][newColumn] = Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text(''));
          }
        } else {
          _data[i][newColumn] = TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _displayTextInputDialog(context);
              },
              child: const Text('-'));
        }
      }
      _columnNames.add(newColumn);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateInput.text = "";
    _columnNames = _data[0].keys.toList();
    //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();

    //// Start listening to changes.
    ctrlsampleSize.addListener(() {});
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Form(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 210,
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 200,
                          height: 200,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: ctrlsampleSize,
                                validator: ((value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter sample size';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('images/Test1.jpg'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          Container(
              child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                // add Column
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 860, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          "Total Parameter : 6",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 8, 0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => startbutton(),
                      child: const Text('Start'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 8, 0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Reset'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 8, 0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Save'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child:
                //****uncomment if use Provider */
                // Container(
                //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //     border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                //   ),
                //   child: ConstrainedBox(
                //     constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                //       maxHeight: 600,
                //       maxWidth: 813,
                //     ),
                //     child: Column(
                //       children: [
                //         Expanded(
                //           child: ChangeNotifierProvider<CheckItemProvider>(
                //               create: (context) => CheckItemProvider(),
                //               child: Consumer<CheckItemProvider>(
                //                   builder: (context, provider, child) {
                //                 provider.getData(context);
                //                 return const Center(
                //                     child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                //                 // when we have the json loaded... let's put the data into a data table widget
                //                 return

                SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: DataTable(
                  headingRowHeight: 30,
                  border: TableBorder.all(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                      (states) => Colors.lightBlue),
                  headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                  columns: _columnNames.map((columnName) {
                    return DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        columnName,
                        // style: const TextStyle(
                        //   fontSize: 18,
                        //   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        // ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  rows:
                      _data // Loops through dataColumnText, each iteration assigning the value to element
                          .map((row) {
                    return DataRow(
                        cells: row.values.map((cellValue) {
                      try {
                        return DataCell(
                          cellValue,
                          onTap: () {},
                        );
                      } catch (e) {
                        return DataCell(Text(cellValue));
                      }
                      ;
                    }).toList());
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //},
            // ),
            // ),
            //   ),
            // ],
            //  ),
            // ),
            // ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please include full code so we can regenerate the issue?

Comment: i update aldy but need to delete few code because of character limit